# how i can start process with large multiline script block in powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

i wanna start process powershell with script block .
 like this code.

```
start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit","-command {
set-Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass -force
get-help get-process
get-command -commandtype cmdlet
...
}"
```

Comment: this command is example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method :

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-command", "help
dir
get-command
"
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument for Command should be another element in the ArgumentList not merged into -command.

i.e.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-noexit", "-command", "Get-Process"
```

This applies whether the thing you're executing is a simple command or a longer command (a very long string).